# MATLAB dicominfo fails in 2015b

Tags: matlab, upgrade, regression, dicom

When trying to open a DICOM file I get this:
    Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

```
Error in dicominfo>parsePerson (line 371)
                    personName(p).(pnParts{q}) = [personName(p).(pnParts{q}) '=' componentParts{q}];
```

However everything used to work smoothly in 2013a.
Does anyone know what is the matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indeed a bug in Matlab R2015b. The solution to change `p` to `q` didn't work for me. This seems to work:

Swap line 336 of dicominfo.m for

```
personName = repmat(makePerson(pnParts),[1,numel(splitRawData)]);
```

Swap line 354 of dicominfo.m for

```
personName(p) = makePerson(pnParts);
```

Comment: Didn't verify but accepting as it works for 2>1 people

Answer (score 1):

OK, it's a bug. Just change one `p` to `q` in line 371 of dicominfo.m. Like this:

```
personName(p).(pnParts{q}) = [personName(q).(pnParts{q}) '=' omponentParts{q}];
```

Comment: i think you can delete this question as it is a typo and will unlikely help anyone. thanks :)

Comment: If it have had existed, then it would have saved me some hour-ish of time,so I'm keeping it.

Comment: Oh I thought you made the typo sorry about that

Comment: Hi, I'm the lead developer of MATLAB's DICOM functionality. I'm really surprised this happened, and I'm not 100% convinced that your fix is correct--although I'll grant that it worked in your case. Would it be possible to send me the file that triggered this error? I'd like to dig into it a little deeper. (jeff.mather@mathworks.com) Thanks!